# Using NSUBST for S-Expression Replacement

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to replace (destructively) all instances of AND in an S-Expression to OR. If each line is denoted by the variable line how would I go about doing this with NSUBST?

Right now I have the following in my loop, say for example line is (TEST (AND)) and I want it to be (TEST (OR))

(NSUBST '(OR) '(AND) '(line))

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Are you doing this in a macro?  Does this expression come from a macro argument, e.g. `&body`?  What I'm trying to say is that you should be careful not to destructively modify literal or constant data: it might not work, and if it works, every reference to it will observe those modifications (quite often unexpected).

Comment: Don't modify literal (quoted) data, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
(nsubst 'or 'and line)
```

Comment: Also since you are quoting the operators you can use `eval` to see if it actually works `(eval (nsubst 'or 'and '(and 0 1)))` = 0

Comment: @Rorschach: Why would you need explicit `eval` for that?

Comment: @Svante because just replacement will leave it unevaluated..`(nsubst 'or 'and '(and 0 1))` => (OR 0 1).

Comment: @Rorschach But don't modify literal data.  Instead do, e.g., `(nsubst 'or 'and (copy-tree '(and 0 1)))`.